# How to declare variable outside if and for statement that already declared in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, updating

I'm trying to update my images table with new ones.

This is my controller:

```
        if(!empty($_FILES['gambar']['name'])){
            $filesNumber        =   sizeof($_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name']);
            $files          =   $_FILES['gambar'];
            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/img/pics/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 2048;
            $config['encrypt_name']      = true;

            for ($i = 0; $i < $filesNumber ; $i++) {
                $_FILES['gambar']['name']       =   $files['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar']['type']       =   $files['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name']   =   $files['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar']['error']      =   $files['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['gambar']['size']       =   $files['size'][$i];

                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if($this->upload->do_upload('gambar')){
                    $data = $this->upload->data();

                    $insert[$i]['kode_asset']   = $this->input->post('kode');
                    $insert[$i]['gambar']       = $data['file_name'];
                }
            }

        $this->db->insert_batch('gambar', $insert);
        redirect('admin/asset','refresh');
        }
```

This is input for multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name="gambar[]" id="gambar" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

But it give `Undefined variable: insert` notice at the `insert_batch` syntax and `You must use the "set" method to update an entry.` db error every time. Can someone help me?

Comment: What's the purpose of this `$_FILES['gambar']['name']       =   $files['name'][$i];`

Comment: just add `$insert = array()` above the for loop

Comment: I just figured how the error showed up. It's because the file didn't uploaded. Now I got another problem, it can upload jpg image files but not with the png. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @RizkyIrmawan Please update your question if you have additional information.

Comment: Get error message like this in the `else` statement `if($this->upload->do_upload('gambar')){}else{ $this->upload->display_errors(); }`

Answer (score 0):

check the statement:

```php
// check filesNumber value, after see this , you may fix this quickly.
 $filesNumber        =   sizeof($_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name']);
```